# MySQL SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (subquery)

Tags: mysql

I have a field that contains a string like so:

```
["688024","688023","688025"]
```

Each of these values relates to an ID in another table.  I can strip the brackets and quotes like so:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(myField,'"',""),'[',''),']','') FROM myTable WHERE myID = 123456
```

This gives me:

```
688024,688023,688025
```

I then want to use this in an `IN` statement like so:

```
SELECT * FROM myOtherTable WHERE myOtherID IN (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(myField,'"',""),'[',''),']','') FROM myTable WHERE myID = 123456)
```

However, it only returns 1 result, which is ID 688024 (the first one).  If I do the following I get 3 results:

```
SELECT * FROM myOtherTable WHERE myOtherID IN (688024,688023,688025)
```

Why would the subquery only give me 1 result?  Thanks.

Comment: A string is not the same a number in MySQL. So MySQL converts "688024,688023,688025" to a number, which is 688024. The real solution is to normalize your database.

Comment: This makes sense! So is there a way of casting "688024,688023,688025" into 3 comma separated numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT *
FROM myOtherTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable t2
              WHERE myID = 123456 AND
              FIND_IN_SET(t1.myOtherID,
                  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(myField, '"', ""), '[', ''), ']', '')) > 0);
```

But note that your current table design is suboptimal, because you are storing CSV data.  A better approach for the `myTable` table would be to have each `myField` value on a separate row, something like this:

```
myID   | myField
123456 | 688024
123456 | 688023
123456 | 688025
```

Then, you would only need a much simpler query:

```
SELECT *
FROM myOtherTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable t2
              WHERE myID = 123456 AND t1.myOtherID = t2.myField);
```

Comment: Yes, `FIND_IN_SET` would do the job, but a better solution is to normalize the data.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks.

I agree with the data restructure - in fact, that's exactly what I'm in the process of.  This is a temporary fix to make 2 systems sync.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `WHERE myID = 123456` isn't conflicting with what you want to achieve? As I look at it, it's causing the problem, it only returns the record with such id.

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer, doesn't it?